# Ethernet over USB (g_ether) shall automatically (re)connect

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

When connecting my embedded device (debian 8) with `g_multi` running to my host PC (debian 9), the mass storage is detected (and automounted, if I want it), but not the Ethernet over USB. I have to do `ifdown usb0; ifup usb0` to establish the connection.

I did try with `auto usb0` and `allow-hotplug usb0` and both in `/etc/network/interfaces` to no avail. Any idea how to fix this? Or should I do a workaround to trigger that ifdown/ifup on detection of the mass storage (and how to do that right)?